# Function using string produced from another function C++

Tags: c++

I had written a function , which is supposed to analyze and use the data (string to be specific) produced from another function and calculate the percentage of chars and print out the results.

this function is of type int but the previous function is of type string. I was thinking of using pointers but I don't know if it's a valid conversion.

I also don't believe that putting a function in another function argument is valid.

here is an almost complete function

```
int percentages(string line)
{
    int overalcount;
    double Leu, Phe, Ile, STA, Val, Ser, Pro, Thr, Ala, Tyr, STO, His, Gln, Asn, Lys, Asp, Glu, Cys, Trp, Arg, Gly;
    int percentage, percentage1, percentage2, percentage3, percentage4, percentage5, percentage6, percentage7;
    int percentage8, percentage9, percentage10, percentage11, percentage12, percentage13, percentage14;
    int percentage15, percentage16, percentage17, percentage18, percentage19, percentage20;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i + 3 < line.length(); i += 3)
    {
        overalcount++;

        if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Phe")
        {
            Phe++;
            if(!Phe == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Phe / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Leu")
        {
            Leu++;
            if(!Leu == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Leu / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Ile")
        {
            Ile++;
            if(!Ile == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Ile / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "STA")
        {
            STA++;
            if(!STA == 0)
            {
                percentage = (STA / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Val")
        {
            Val++;
            if(!Val == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Val / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Ser")
        {
            Ser++;
            if(!Ser == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Ser / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Pro")
        {
            Pro++;
            if(!Pro == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Pro / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Thr")
        {
            Thr++;
            if(!Thr == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Thr / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Ala")
        {
            Ala++;
            if(!Ala == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Ala / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Tyr")
        {
            Tyr++;
            if(!Tyr == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Tyr / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "STO")
        {
            STO++;
            if(!STO == 0)
            {
                percentage = (STO / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "His")
        {
            His++;
            if(!His == 0)
            {
                percentage = (His / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Gln")
        {
            Gln++;
            if(!Gln == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Gln / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Asn")
        {
            Asn++;
            if(!Asn == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Asn / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Lys")
        {
            Lys++;
            if(!Lys == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Lys / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Asp")
        {
            Asp++;
            if(!Asp == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Asp / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Glu")
        {
            Glu++;
            if(!Glu == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Glu / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Cys")
        {
            Cys++;
            if(!Cys == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Cys / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Trp")
        {
            Trp++;
            if(!Trp == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Trp / overalcount) * 100;
            }
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Arg")
        {
            Arg++;
            if(!Arg == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Arg / overalcount) * 100;
            }   
        }
        else if(line.substr(i, 3) == "Gly")
        {
            Gly++;
            if(!Gly == 0)
            {
                percentage = (Gly / overalcount) * 100;
            }   
        }
    }

    if(!percentage == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Phe: " <<percentage <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage1 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Leu: " <<percentage1 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Ile: " <<percentage2 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of STA: " <<percentage3 <<endl;         
    }
    if(!percentage4 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Val: " <<percentage4 <<endl;         
    }
    if(!percentage5 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Ser: " <<percentage5 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage6 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Pro: " <<percentage6 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage7 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Thr: " <<percentage7 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage8 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Ala: " <<percentage8 <<endl;
    }
    if(!percentage9 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Percentage of Tyr: " <<percentage9 <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the argument "string line" is supposedly the string produced by the previous function. But it is instead recognizing the line that is read from the input filestream.

Comment: Please educate yourself about arrays and case / switch statements... also, doing ++ on a double almost certainly does not do what you expect (I would be incredibly surprised if it did). You need to use an int instead.

Comment: I hope not to sound offensive, but that function looks really ... gross.

Comment: well you're being honest so thanks. im not very adept at C++ lol

Comment: There's also a logic problem.  Let's say you find one "Leu" and then 9 "Phe".  The percentage of "Phe" will correctly report 90%, but the percentage of "Leu" will be 100% because it's never updated after the first time, when it was 100%.  You would be much better off reducing this to a word counting problem.  @Patashu: you can't `switch` `std::string`.

Comment: Those `!x == 0` could be modified into `x != 0` to be more straightforward.

Comment: i thought this was a word counting method..

Comment: It is.  It's just ... well, kind of a dumb one.

Answer (score 2):

Here, take this much less gross function:

```
int percentages(string line)
{
    map<string, int> words;
    double count = line.length() / 3;
    for (int i = 0; i + 3 < line.length(); i += 3)
        ++words[line.substr(i, 3)];

    string find[10] = {"Phe", "Leu", "Ile", "STA", "Val", "Ser", "Pro", "Thr", "Ala", "Tyr"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        cout << "Percentage of " << find[i] << ": " << words[find[i]] / count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've seen things on this site that made me feel like my brain was trying to claw its way out of my skull.  This one wasn't that bad.  I will admit that it might be the winner in the "saying the least in the most lines" category.

Comment: At least this one put some effort into it, it's true.